# Hibernate taking too long time to insert into tabel 10 to 15 seconds?

Tags: java, hibernate

Actually I am new to hibernate I have written a simple program in hibernate it takes around 10 to 15 seconds to execute is there some problem with my code please help.

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.Transaction;  
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;  
public class StoreData 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Configuration  cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  
        Session session=factory.openSession();  
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  

        Employee e1=new Employee();   
        e1.setFirstName("ABC");  
        e1.setLastName("DEF"); 

        Employee e2=new Employee();   
        e2.setFirstName("HIJ");  
        e2.setLastName("KLM");      

        session.persist(e1);
        session.persist(e2);

        t.commit();  

        session.close();  

        System.out.println("successfully saved");  
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean the whole program? Are you including the time to set things up into that?

Comment: yes the whole program is taking 10 to 15 seconds. I dint understood your 2nd question exactly what are you trying to say.

Comment: I'm saying that `session.persist(e1);` doesn't take a lot of time, but `BasicConfigurator.configure();` and others does.

Comment: I removed BasicConfigurator,configure(); but still taking around 5 seconds anything else I can remove from that code.

Comment: You're misunderstanding. It will always take some time to set things up. You're just measuring the wrong thing.

Comment: You are measuring wrong time. We use hibernate in our production server because of its performance and ease. It takes very less time to insert into the table. Just read about Hibernate sessionFactory and how it improves the performance of query execution.

Comment: Depending on the database system you're using it might be pretty expensive to acquire a connection. Maybe that's the effect you see here.